# can we change catalog search url in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change the catalog search URL from

```
www.abc.com/catalogsearch/result/?cat=0&q=test

to 

www.abc.com/test.html
```

Is there any way?

Comment: may i know the reason for this purpose ?

Comment: It's not possibe to transform your param test to test.html

Comment: @Rathinam, I have disallow catalog search in robots.txt for seo purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute splash extension for change the url:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/attribute-splash-pages.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible within Magento. However, there is some kind of workaround to create a situation like the one you want. You can create synonyms for specific search terms. So if a lot of people search for "test", you can redirect them to a page, which contains the product, category or anything else that's related to "test".

To do this, you need to login to the Magento backend and go to **Catalog > Search Terms**. Here you'll find an overview with all used search terms in your webshop. You can click one or create a new search term by clicking "Add New Search Term". In this screen, you can set a redirect URL. This makes it possible to redirect the user from a search term to a specific page. This page can be on your site or on any other site as well.